# How to append a tensor with model output?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a simple Neural network made in Keras.

I do data prep in Pandas and then convert my test / train splits to tensors;

```
train_features = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_features)
test_features = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_features)
train_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels)
test_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_labels)
```

Then, using thse to fit & validate the model.

If the output is like below

```
model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
z = model.predict(test_features)
```

How would I write back each prediction to the input tensor (in this case `test_features`)?

Comment: Do not overwrite the original pandas dataframe, you are going to need them again later. You can do something like `test_features_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_features)`. Then after you compute the outputs do `test_features["output"] = z.numpy()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to assume that the predictions are in the same order as the original df, so I can just concat them?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. Unless of course you are explicitly reshuffling the data somewhere else in the code.